# Show that this is an integral basis of the ring of integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Show that $1,\sqrt{3},\sqrt{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{6}}{2}$ is an integral basis for $\mathcal{O}_K$ where $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3},\sqrt{6})$.

Clearly, the rank of $\mathcal{O}_K$ is indeed $4$, so it suffices to show that this set spans. My objective is to take an arbitrary $\alpha\in \mathcal{O}_K$ and show that it can be written in terms of my claimed basis with integer coefficients, but I am not sure how one would achieve this. I know there is the exercise treating the general case in Marcus's $\textit{Number Fields}$, but I am interested in keeping the computations straightforward and limited to this concrete example. (In any case, I do not quite see how the exercise in Marcus is done either.)

Any and all help would be appreciated.

Comment: The usual starting point is to use the fact that $1, \sqrt3,\ldots$ is a $\mathbb Q$ basis of $K$. Hence, any element of $\mathcal O_K$ is a rational linear combination of $1, \sqrt3,\ldots$. So assume that $a + b\sqrt{3}+c\sqrt{2}+d\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt6}2\in\mathcal O_K$ and prove that $a,b,c,d\in\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Mathmo123 I agree with everything you just said, and indeed I have been pursuing such a line of reasoning. But I am having trouble with precisely the last thing you say: it is not quite so easy for me to show that $a,b,c,d\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Have you already computed the discriminant of the supposed basis? I am not sure if this will solve the problem immediately but computing the discriminant is always good starting point....

Comment: Indeed, @russoo, that would be my strategy: compute the discriminant of the suspect basis, and by whatever method, the discriminant of (the integers of) the quartic field. If they’re equal, you’re done. By the way, there’s a theorem that the full discriminant is (except for sign) the product of the local discriminants; that could help in finding the discriminant of the quartic.

Comment: I think most basic methods for finding the ring of integers somehow involve the discriminant. Unfortunately, Marcus has hidden these methods somewhere in the exercises (but it is still a great book on algebraic number theory). A theorem which might help for your problem is exercise 27, (c). Sometimes, the statement from exercise 22 can also be helpful. But since I don't know the discriminant and I am absolutely not willing to compute it by myself, I can't say more about it right now...

Comment: @russoo Indeed I am able to compute the discriminant of the supposed basis, but as Lubin states, the hard part is computing the discriminant of the integers of the biquadratic field.  This is the part that I cannot do. Also, I am not sure why if the discriminants are equal this implies that they the two rings are the same. I don't think in general that discriminants classify all rings, and a prioiri the supposed basis does not give the ring of integers of a number field.

Comment: @lagicol, that the supposed basis is an integral basis if the discriminants are equal follows for example from exercise 27 (c) from Marcus' book which you are using. Could you edit your question and add the discriminant you computed?

Comment: Equality of discriminants forces equality of the rings in the case that one is contained in the other because in this case $\Delta'=m^2\Delta$, where $m$ is the index $(R:R')$. Easily seen.

Answer (score 3):

Here’s another way of doing it, using the (relatively easy) fact that a basis of $K$ is an integral basis (i.e. a $\Bbb Z$-basis of $\mathcal O$) if and only if it‘s a basis locally at every prime of $\Bbb Z$.

I checked the discriminant of your basis, and found $2^8\cdot3^2$, so that your basis is good at all primes not dividing $6$ — the discriminant of any true basis would divide your $2^8\cdot3^2$. Now to check $2$ and $3$:

I’m going to make typing easier for myself by writing your fourth basis element $\beta=\frac{\sqrt2+\sqrt6}2=\frac{1+\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}$.

Now above $2$, there’s only one prime $\mathfrak p_2$ of $K$, with ramification index $4$, and I checked (just by computing the norms down to $\Bbb Q$) that $\beta-1=\pi$ is locally a prime, that is $v_{\mathfrak p_2}(\pi)=1$, furthermore that $v_{\mathfrak p_2}(\sqrt2\,)=2$ (of course), and equally obviously that $v_{\mathfrak p_2}(1+\sqrt3-\sqrt2)=3$, since it’s $\pi\sqrt2$. Thus, locally at $2$, your basis is good, since together with $1$, the numbers I checked must be a basis.

Now, at $3$, the situation is a bit different. There’s still just one prime above $3$, call it $\mathfrak p_3$, but the ramification index and the residue field degree are both $2$. Now $1$ and $\sqrt2$ form a basis of the unramified part, i.e. give independent elements of the residue field (over $\Bbb F_3$), and $v_{\mathfrak p _3}(\sqrt3\,)=1$, so all we need to do is find something else of valuation $1$, but which, as element of $\mathfrak p_3/\mathfrak p_3^2$ is not an $\Bbb F_3$-multiple of $\sqrt3$, this “something” to be a $\Bbb Z$-linear combination of elements of your proposed basis. But we get:
$$
\beta+\sqrt2=\frac{1+\sqrt3+2}{\sqrt2}=\frac{3+\sqrt3}{\sqrt2}\equiv\frac{\sqrt2\cdot\sqrt3}{2}\pmod{\mathfrak p_3^2}\,,
$$
which fills the bill.

So, without dependence on any further discriminant calculation, your basis turns out to be an integral basis.